# Migrate databases from local django to heroku

Tags: django, database, postgresql, heroku, migration

I have an application in Django that I deploy in heroku.
The deploy works well, but my model's database was not migrate.

After the deploy, I run again localy:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

After, I do:

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

And after I run the server and wait it works well:

```
heroku run python manage.py runserver
```

I have 3 models:

cliente, categoria, produto

`produto` has a `ForeignKey` to `categoria`. So, localy, I have 3 databases:

`produtos_produto`, `produtos_categoria`, `cliente`.

I use `PostgreSQL` as database localy and in heroku.

But in heroku, I don't have any of this databases.

When I run the server, in browser I have the following  answer:

```
ProgrammingError at /

relation "produtos_categoria" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ia"."descricao", "produtos_categoria"."logo" FROM "produtos_...
                                                             ^

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://redewebsite.herokuapp.com/
Django Version:     1.9.2
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    

relation "produtos_categoria" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ia"."descricao", "produtos_categoria"."logo" FROM "produtos_...
                                                             ^

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 64
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.11
Python Path:    

['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-19.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Sex, 4 Mar 2016 17:50:43 +0000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must run makemigrations locally, then commit those generated migration files to git. Heroku will run then automatically when you deploy.

Comment: I understand it now. We need to make git add on the migrations file and push them before.